# How to block elements only on exact URL

Tags: adblock

I'm trying to apply a filter to youtube so that all the suggested videos on its homepage are hidden. I'm using ublock origin (uses EasyList rules mostly) and it's easy enough to do through the UI, and adds this rule:

```
www.youtube.com##.ytd-two-column-browse-results-renderer.style-scope > .ytd-rich-grid-renderer.style-scope
```

This works great, but the problem is that it applies that rule all over youtube, and so if I go to a creator's channel and try to look at all the videos (for example: youtube.com/c/{username}/videos) then all of those get hidden as well.

I'm guessing it's pretty simple, but how can I apply this rule *only* to the base youtube url?

Comment: Trying to do the same thing, took me a while to find it. You want this filter: `www.youtube.com##:matches-path(/^/$/) ytd-app`

Answer (score -1):

To add on to the above answer (which I've been looking for for a while, so thanks!), you can switch out the "ytd-app" for "ytd-two-column-browse-results-renderer.style-scope" if you still want to keep the access to the search bar on the front page.